# what's the best track size for PCI card and 256 pin QFP chip?

Tags: pcb

I tried to develope PCB on altium,
what's the best track size for PCI card edge and 256 pin QFP chip ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct trace width depends on what trace impedance you want and your PCB stackup.  There is no way that we can tell you a useful number.  But you can Google "microstrip impedance calculator" and calculate it for yourself.